# Passing values from main class to other classes in Java

Tags: java, class

I'm on a project that requires passing values from main class to other classes. All of the classes are correctly working when they have their main functions. However, my project should have only one main class that calls other functions in other classes.

An example for main and another class is below. I want to scan the input through main class and pass it to parse class. Current implementation gives two error which are:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at url.checker.Parse.GetInput(Parse.java:16)
    at url.checker.Main.main(Main.java:14)
Java Result: 1
```

**Given input: -url=google.com,-time=5,-email=asdfg@hotmail.com**

Main.java:

```
    package url.checker;

    import java.util.Scanner;

        public class Main {

          public static void main(String[] args) 
          {


            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter the parameters as '-url=' , '-time=' , '-email='.");
            Parse.s = in.nextLine();
            Parse.GetInput(Parse.s);
          }
      }
```

Parse.java:

```
        package url.checker;
        import java.util.Scanner;

        public class Parse 
        {
          static String s;
          static String result[];

          public static void GetInput(String s)
          {
            int i;

            for(i=0;i<3;i++)
            {
              if (s.startsWith("-url="))
                result[0] = s.substring(5, s.length());
              else if (s.startsWith("-time="))
                result[1] = s.substring(6, s.length());
              else if (s.startsWith("-email="))
                result[2] = s.substring(7, s.length());
              else
                System.out.println("You didn't give any input.");
            }
          }
        }
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: PLEASE!!! Format your code!

Comment: You could change `Parse.s = in.nextLine();Parse.GetInput(Parse.s);` to `Parse.GetInput(in.nextLine());` if you want to remove an redundant step. Also there are nicer ways to do what you want even though your way will work when changing the code as explained in the answer. Hint, create a `Parse` object and use it instead of having everything static.

Comment: There is no such thing as Main class in java (and in programming in general). This is a debug-my-code and is useless for the heritage. Saying that it is the only class that can call other methods is nonsense either. Who assigned you these task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 static String result[];
```

You never initialized the array; Since its a static it gets initialized to *null* by default.

Initialize using `static String[] strings = new String[10];`. This will hold 10 elements of `String`.

Comment: I edited your answer to complete the code, hope you don't mind :)

Comment: Appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean that this has nothing to do with the Main class?

Comment: Yes. Just make sure your array is initialized before accessing it.